# Legend in box not centered

Tags: matlab, plot, legend

**Problem**

The legend of the plot I create using plotyy is not centered in its box as illustrated in the picture:

[image]

This is the first time this happened to me and the problem keeps on being there after exporting into all sorts of formarts as well. I am using Matlab R2016a.

**Code**

I use the following code to plot the legend:

```
a=sprintf('Test')
b=sprintf('Test.\nTest Test')
c=sprintf('Test\nTest')
d=sprintf('TestTest\nTest')
e=sprintf('Test\nTest')
f=sprintf('Test\nTest Test')
hLegend=legend([l1,l2,r1,r2,r3,r4], a, b, c, d, e, f);
set([gca,hXLabel,hYLabel,hLegend] , 'FontName'   , 'Helvetica','FontSize', 8) 
set(hLegend,'Fontsize',8,'Location', 'southoutside', 'Orientation','horizontal')
```

Therefore the question, did anyone have this problem already? And is there a way to fix it or can I center the legend somehow manually?

**An Executable Code Sample**

```
h=figure
x=[1:10]
y=[1:10]
hold on
yyaxis left
l1=plot(x,y)
l2=plot(x,2*y)
hYLabel=ylabel('Test') 

yyaxis right
r1=plot(x,y.^2)
r2=plot(x,y.^3)
r3=plot(x,10*y)
r4=plot(x,20*y)


hYLabel=ylabel('Test2')
hXLabel = xlabel('TestTest]');
a=sprintf('Test')
b=sprintf('Test.\nTest Test')
c=sprintf('Test\nTest')
d=sprintf('Test\nTest')
e=sprintf('Test\nTest')
f=sprintf('TestTest\nTest')
hLegend=legend([l1,l2,r1,r2,r3,r4], a, b, c, d, e, f);
set([gca,hXLabel,hYLabel,hLegend] , 'FontName'   , 'Helvetica','FontSize', 8) 
set(hLegend,'Fontsize',8,'Location', 'southoutside', 'Orientation','horizontal')
set(gca,'LineWidth',1.0)
set(l1, 'LineWidth',1.5,'LineStyle','-')
set(l2, 'LineWidth',1.5,'LineStyle','-.')
set(r1, 'LineWidth',1.5,'LineStyle','-')
set(r2, 'LineWidth',1.5,'LineStyle','-.')
set(r3, 'LineWidth',1.5)
set(r4, 'LineWidth',1.5,'LineStyle','- -')

hold off
```

Although not displaying the original data used, I get the same problem using the example above.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I am getting an error message: *Undefined function or variable 'l1'.* can you please post an executable code sample?

Comment: @Rotem i added an executable version of the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I a guess the problem is that `a=sprintf('Test')` is a single line, and other like `b=sprintf('Test.\nTest Test')` are multiple lines.

When all legend entries are two text lines, the text is centered correctly.

Solution: replace `a=sprintf('Test')` with `a=sprintf('Test\n\0.')`.
That makes `a` two text lines, when the second line is a blank character.

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer, that is already a big help. Do you know if there is a way to get the first one centered in front of the line tho ? Because in the case here no the first "Test" looks a bit lost

Comment: No, I could not find a way setting the vertical alignment of the fist label.

Comment: Replacing the order - (placing `Test` second), solves the problem: `a=sprintf('Test');hLegend=legend([l2,l1,r1,r2,r3,r4], b, a, c, d, e, f);` (In case it's acceptable).